# Animated Border Menu - Closing menu with menu item

Tags: javascript

I'm using this animated menu for one of my site, and I'd like that when user click on menu items it also close the menu :

https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/AnimatedBorderMenus/index5.html

Any idea ?

I tried to edit bordermenu.js but couldn't find the solution

Answer (score 0):

First, look in borderMenu.js. You will see that the way the menu is opened and closed is by adding and removing classes:

```
classie.remove( menu, 'bt-menu-open' );
classie.add( menu, 'bt-menu-close' );
```

With this understanding, look on line 45, where you see a conditional check inside the creation of an event listener:

```
if( classie.has( menu, 'bt-menu-open' ) ) {
    resetMenu();
}
```

You want to update that condition or create a new condition that listens for a click on an element with another class, let's say `bt-menu-item`:

```
<li class="bt-menu-item"><a href="#">About us</a></li>
```

and your new condition:

```
if( classie.has( menu, 'bt-menu-open' ) || classie.has( menu, 'bt-menu-item' ) ) {
    resetMenu();
}
```

If you need to do more when you hear a click on the menu item, make it a separate conditional statement.

Comment: Thank you so much Josh for the quick answer. However, I tried your solution and it didn't work. Here is where I'm trying this solution : https://vincentmoreautesting.com/thecbp2

Comment: Anyone could help?